# Serving list of images in spring boot

Tags: image, spring-boot, static

I have created assets folder inside resources. I want to display list of image names in the assets folder. By clicking image name, it should open the particular image. I can access the images separately but how to display all the images as file explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might use `ResourcePatternResolver`:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/assets")
public class AssetController {

    @Autowired
    private ResourcePatternResolver resolver;

    @GetMapping("")
    @ResponseBody
    public String resources() throws IOException {
        final String root = resolver.getResource("classpath:/static/assets").getURI().toString();

        final Resource[] resources = resolver
            .getResources("classpath:/static/assets/**/*.png");
        final List<String> fileNames = Stream.of(resources)
            .filter(Resource::isFile)
            .map(r -> {
                try {
                    return r.getURI().toString().replace(root, "");
                } catch (final IOException e) {
                    throw new IOError(e);
                }
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        final StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
        html.append("<html>");
        html.append("<ul>");
        for (final String fileName : fileNames) {
            html.append("<li>");
            html.append("<a href=\"/assets" + fileName + "\">" + fileName + "</a>");
            html.append("</li>");
        }
        html.append("</ul>");
        html.append("</html>");
        return html.toString();
    }

}
```